# Switch between applications pinned to windows taskbar causes taskbar to appear

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

**OS:** Windows 10

**Abstract**:
I've got few apps pinned to taskbar so I can perform fast-switch to any of it using "Win + digit" shortcut from any desktop.
Also, I've set taskbar to hide automatically.

**Problem:** Every time i'm performing fast-switch to another app with "Win + digit", before switching, OS makes taskbar to re-appear for a second, which turns fast-switch to annoying-switch.

**Question:**
Is there a way to avoid taskbar pop-up during application fast-switch?

Answer (score 0):

WinKey + Digit is implemented differently than Alt-Tab .

Alt-Tab brings a working window up and does not need the taskbar to work in and see the apps.

WinKey + Digit uses the taskbar to find the number (0,1,2,3,4..) to bring up. It exposes the taskbar to do this.

Whether Alt-Tab or WinKey + Digit, Windows has a working view on the screen of what it happening. That is likely helpful for some folk.

Win + Digit will activate an app (like Windows Explorer (and so underline it in Taskbar). This is part of the Digit numbering. Alt-Tab does not do this.

So, no,  there is no native way to switch tasks without unhiding the taskbar.  This is true for Windows 10 21H1 19043 production and V21390.1 Insider.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this answer because when I'm pressing `Win+V` for paste from history there is also `WinKey` involved. But no taskbar shows up. It means that `WinKey` pressing does not always involves taskbar.
So, I believe there should be some some Registry tweak, like `Dword Taskbar.Annoying=00000001` which I may change to avoid this behavior.

Comment: The way I have posted is the way Winkey + Digit was implemented. I have checked various articles and there is no way to change this natively nor any windows way I have seen to change this.

Answer (score 0):

The taskbar only reappears because the <kbd>Win</kbd> key shows the
Start Menu, but it also incidentally brings up with it the Taskbar in which
it's embedded.

You could possibly reduce the annoyance by replacing your typing with
a faster script that will send the keys
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>digit</kbd>
much faster than you can.

A good tool for that is [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
But you could also set it to run the programs directly by some other
shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>digit</kbd>.

---

An example AutoHotkey script to execute the first pinned program
when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>:

```
^1::Send,{LWin down}1{LWin up}
```

To run the program directly without passing through the taskbar
and so avoiding showing the taskbar entirely:

```
^1::Run,"C:\path\prog1.exe"
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: `faster script that will send the keys Win+digit much faster than you can.`

Any advise on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I added some more information.